# Use of ViewState in an auto scaled web app

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, viewstate

Use of the ASP.NET view state can cause issues within a multi-server environment.

[Resolving view state message authentication code (MAC) errors](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2915218/resolving-view-state-message-authentication-code-mac-errors)

> View state is information that is round-tripped between WebForms
>   (.aspx) pages in an ASP.NET application. ...
>
> Because the __VIEWSTATE field contains important information that is
>   used to reconstruct the page on postback, make sure that an attacker
>   cannot to tamper with this field. ...
>
> To prevent this kind of tampering attack, the __VIEWSTATE field is
>   protected by a message authentication code (MAC). ASP.NET validates
>   the MAC that is submitted together with the __VIEWSTATE payload when a
>   postback occurs.

There are a number of approaches to mitigate this issue with a multi-server environment (elaborated within the article linked above).

Do these approaches need to be applied within an Azure Web App that is set to auto-scale?

Comment: Have you tried deploying a multi-instance app service and testing PostBack behavior?  I can't say this for sure, but I feel like app services handle this kind of stuff for you, such as decrypting values on one instance that were encrypted on another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I checked the [document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2915218/resolving-view-state-message-authentication-code-mac-errors) you mentioned about resolving view state message authentication code (MAC) errors.

As the case about the web application is running in a farm (multi-server environment) states as follows:

> Some web hosting services, such as **Microsoft Azure websites**, **take steps to synchronize each application's auto-generated key across their back-end servers. This lets applications that have not specified an explicit  element to continue working in these environments, even if the application is running in a farm**. If your application is running on a third-party hosting service, please contact your hosting provider to determine whether this situation applies to you.

Also, I tried to create my ASP.NET WebForm application and deploy to Azure Web App (multiple instances), it could work as expected.